# Nvidia Tao Training FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'unet/results1/model.step-0.tlt'

Tags: nvidia, unet-neural-network

[image: This is the error I am getting while training on tao unet.]

This below is my spec file I am using for training the dataset on tao unet. All the directory are present there but when it tries to save the first checkpoint it throws me this error.
The command I am using for training is ' tao unet train -e unet/config.yaml -k amns -r amns_results'

```
# Sample model config for to instantiate a resnet18 model freeze blocks 0, 1
# with all shortcuts having projection layers.

model_config {
  num_layers: 18
  all_projections: true
  arch: "resnet"
  freeze_blocks: 0
  freeze_blocks: 1
  use_batch_norm: true
  initializer: HE_UNIFORM
  training_precision {
    backend_floatx: FLOAT32
  }
  model_input_height: 320
  model_input_width: 320
  model_input_channels: 3
}
training_config {
  batch_size: 2
  epochs: 3
  log_summary_steps: 10
  checkpoint_interval: 1
  loss: "cross_dice_sum"
  learning_rate:0.0001
  lr_scheduler {
    cosine_decay {
      alpha : 0.01
      decay_steps: 500
    }
  }
  regularizer {
    type: L2
    weight: 3.00000002618e-09
  }
  optimizer {
    adam {
      epsilon: 9.99999993923e-09
      beta1: 0.899999976158
      beta2: 0.999000012875
    }
  }
}
dataset_config {
    dataset: "custom"
    augment: True
    resize_padding: True
    resize_method: BILINEAR
    augmentation_config {
      spatial_augmentation {
        hflip_probability : 0.5
        vflip_probability : 0.5
        crop_and_resize_prob : 0.5
      }
      brightness_augmentation {
        delta: 0.2
      }
    }

    input_image_type: "grayscale"
    train_images_path:"/workspace/segmentation/dataset/amns/train/images"
    train_masks_path:"/workspace/segmentation/dataset/amns/train/labels"
    val_images_path:"/workspace/segmentation/dataset/amns/val/images"
    val_masks_path:"/workspace/segmentation/dataset/amns/val/labels"
    test_images_path:"/workspace/segmentation/dataset/amns/test"
    data_class_config {
      target_classes {
      name: "foreground"
      mapping_class: "foreground"
      label_id: 0
    }
    target_classes {
      name: "background"
      mapping_class: "background"
      label_id: 1
    }
  }
}
```

I tried different directories also but it throws the same error each time, in the amns_resuls folder it saving some files like output, log but no any file present there with the name model.step-0.tlt